# The Rails Metal in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to implement some Rack middleware.

I know (but maybe I am wrong!) that, before of version 3, there was the Rails Metal "system" to handle those. But now?!

**Where in my Rails application I have to locate files to use for middleware purposes** (before of version 3, if I am not wrong, the folder was named 'metal')**? then, how I must state them in the `application.rb` file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the following blog post, that may answer your question:

http://tektastic.com/2010/07/rails3-rack-and-where-did-my-metal-go.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Rails on Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) page on Rails Guides.

Your own middlewares can be stored in lib and can be required at the top of application.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rails-and-merb-merge-plugin-api-part-3-of-6/ for how to create a "Metal" controller

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2010/05/28/how-to-create-your-own-rack-middleware-class-in-ruby-on-rails/ may be helpful for you.

It basically suggests to put your class in /lib/class_name.rb  and then instruct it to be used like

```
 Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
   config.middleware.use "ClassName"
 ...
```

I believe you are right there is no more "metal" option in rails 3 http://tektastic.com/2010/07/rails3-rack-and-where-did-my-metal-go.html you have to use a rack middleware instead.  I'm unsure if this causes a performance hit or not.